# How can I save the data that is loaded in a gridview in the database?

Tags: database, gridview, yii2, save, yii2-advanced-app

**I have a code in yii2 advanced that loads a list of students according to the course they belong to, it is to take attendance, the data of each student is loaded correctly in the gridview but when saving it is not saved in the database.
this is my code in index.php**

```
$this->title = 'Asistencias';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="asistencia-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'alumno',
            'nombres',
            'apellidos',
            [  
                'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                 'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return [
                    'checked' => true
                ];}
            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?= Html::a('Guardar', ['create', 'criterio' => $criterio], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>
```

**my controller
This index loads the students according to their course**

```
public function actionIndex($criterio)
    {
        $this->criterio=$criterio;
         $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => "SELECT a.alumno, a.nombres, a.apellidos 
                      FROM alumnos a 
                      INNER JOIN matriculas m ON a.ALUMNO = m.ALUMNO 
                      WHERE m.CURSO = :criterio 
                      ORDER BY a.apellidos",
            'params' => [':criterio' => $criterio],
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'criterio' => $criterio,
        ]);
    }
```

**this is my save in my controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    /* Obtenemos los datos del formulario*/
    $alumnos = $request->post('alumno', []);
     /* Creamos un nuevo modelo de formulario y verificamos si se ha enviado el formulario*/
    
    $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
    /* Recorremos los alumnos y guardamos la asistencia*/
    foreach ($alumnos as $alumno) {
        $asistencia = new Asistencia();
        $asistencia->ALUMNO = $alumno;
        $matricula = Matricula::findOne(['ALUMNO' => $alumno]);
        $asistencia->MATRICULA =$matricula;
        $asistencia->fecha = $fecha;
        $asistencia->asiste = $request->post("asistencia_$alumno", 'no');
        VarDumper::dump($asistencia);
        if ($asistencia->validate()) {
            $asistencia->save();
        } else {
            var_dump($asistencia->getErrors()); /* Revisa los errores de validación*/
        }
    }
    /* Enviamos un mensaje de éxito*/
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'La asistencia se ha guardado correctamente');
    /* Redirigimos a la página de inicio*/
    return $this->redirect(['index', 'criterio' => $request->get('criterio')]);
}
```

**this is my rules in the model**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['ALUMNO', 'MATRICULA', 'fecha'], 'required'],
            [['MATRICULA'], 'integer'],
            [['fecha'], 'safe'],
            [['ALUMNO'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['asiste'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
            [['ALUMNO', 'MATRICULA', 'fecha'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['ALUMNO', 'MATRICULA', 'fecha']],
            [['MATRICULA'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Matriculas::class, 'targetAttribute' => ['MATRICULA' => 'NUMEROMATRICULA']],
            [['ALUMNO'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Alumnos::class, 'targetAttribute' => ['ALUMNO' => 'ALUMNO']],
        ];
    }
```

**I have tried to loop through the grid view and get the same result, I get the save message, but it doesn't save to the database**

Answer (score 0):

There is no post data submittet so `$request->post` is empty. You should wrap your grid view inside an `<form>` and use a submit button to send form data. Andd maybe you want to add propper `name` attribute to your checkboxes.

The following code I haven't tested. Maybe some improvements must be done...

```
<?php 

$form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => ['create', 'criterio' => $criterio]]);

echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'alumno',
            'nombres',
            'apellidos',
            [  
                'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                'name' => 'checkbox_column',
                'checkboxOptions' => function($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return [
                    'checked' => true,
                ];}
            ],
        ],
    ]);

echo Html::submitButton('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);

ActiveForm::end(); 

?>
```

Comment: You don't need to set the name property explicitly. `yii\grid\CheckboxColumn` uses "selection" as default value for `name` property.